# Definition of a non-pertubative Quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, non-perturbative

How do you define a [non-perturbative Quantum field theory](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=non+perturbative+qft). What does it mean? I was just digging around some math about the meaning of $Z_1$, and such in terms of probabilities. It turns out these and associated counter terms are derived via perturbation theory. So the question is , if you associate meaning to things like probability of self interaction and such, how do you make these things make sense if you are working non-perturbatively.  What is a self interaction outside of perturbation theory?

I mean  considering some probable sketch, for some arbitrary calculations , something looking like the lines below might appear, then some cleaver physics is said.

$1 + \Sigma_a$

$\Gamma^{n} \rightarrow Z_{b} \bar{\Gamma^{m}}$

ok so what is a self interaction in non-pertubative models like.

Is a non-pertubative model real? Can it make sense. . . . I don't know  .. . . . .

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31930/2451 and links therein.